# Weird experience during meditation

Tags: meditation, mindfulness, yoga

I had a weird experience couple of days ago while doing meditation, I hope someone more expert than me could help me understand.Two months ago I started practicing 30 min of yoga and 30 min of mindfulness meditation daily, everything was going good and I felt some changes in me, little by little, I felt I was becoming kind of more aware of myself and my thoughts were slowly become less strong in my mind as I was slowly able to focus deeply inside myself. The other day while I was in a deep state , without thoughts I felt something at the bottom of my spine become hotter and hotter and all of a sudden a warm powerful energy moved upward my back. I immediately felt an intense feeling of ecstasy (as I would take drugs), my head started to spin and I lost balance. Also I had a strong sense of nausea and I had diarrea. I also felt that something was released at the level of my hips. At that point I got really scared and I opened my eyes but the feeling was still there, I felt really peaceful , complete absence of thoughts and like if I was completely extraneous of my body and nothing in life was really important anymore. Also I noticed my senses were a lot more accurate. That feeling decreased a bit over the night and the day after I wakes up completely in hang over, and I remember I could see the colours a lot more bright, and I was really sensible to light. I got really scared From this experience and I’m not able to do meditation anymore , I feel like that if I dig a little bit inside me I can “touch” that  energy again but I don’t want to!can someone explains what happened to me ? Sorry for my bad English , I’m not native English speaker. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

It’s called a “kundalini awakening” in yoga, and “tummo” in Tibetan Buddhism. Seek out a qualified teacher who can guide you through this, as it is both a beautiful and a possibly dangerous event. You can get lost in it and suffer various emotional or motivational problems, but properly harnessed it can launch you into major spiritual advancements. The key is to understand what is happening to you and how you work with it. But be careful, as many yoga teachers are ill-prepared to help with something so profound, as ‘modern’ yoga practices are often focused more on external body forms, rather than on energy movements in the subtle energy body.

Congratulations, and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with James.

You are describing something normal, there is nothing to worry about. You probably did some nice progress, so congrats about that.

If you can talk with a teacher, that would be great. If you can't, then be kind to yourself and remember that it's normal, so there is no reason to worry about it or get too attached to it.

Your English is really good by the way.